# xlwings RunPython with function arguments

Tags: python, vba, xlwings

I am trying to run the RunPython function from a button in excel. I would like the function to take a parameter from a box in excel, something like this:

```
Sub ImportData()
    Dim choice As String
    choice = Range("B2").Value
    RunPython ("import Excel_module; Excel_module.importing_data(choice)")
End Sub
```

Is this a possibility? And if so how do I write the code? I would prefer not to use UDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in two ways:

1) By using `RunPython` as you do:

You'll need to use string concatenation:

```
RunPython ("import Excel_module; Excel_module.importing_data(" & choice & ")")
```

2) Or if you are on Windows only then you can also use the `xw.sub` decorator and use the imported function from VBA as if it was a native VBA function, see the [docs](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html#macros). It isn't currently shown in the docs but they accept arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 2 more single quotes:

```
RunPython ("import Excel_module; Excel_module.importing_data('" & choice & "')")
```